# context menu - javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to add, via javascript an item to the right click context menu on a website, how do I do that?

I have been looking around the web but have found nothing, so if you have a link to a good article that would be great.

I also know there is some compatibility issues with Opera but I am not worried about that right now.

Thanks, R.

Of course I post and instantly find a good tutorial:

http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-context-menu-tutorial.htm

Comment: So it would still be the browser's context menu, but with something specific to your website added?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has [Context Menu](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) implementation.
[Here](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/contextMenu/demo/) is a live demo.

Comment: Both links are broken now - has the site been archived, by any chance?

Comment: Here's a simple implementation of a JQuery context menu that I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app/4502207#4502207

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo!'s [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/) library has a nice menu component, which has a [ContextMenu](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/#usingcontextmenu). You'll have the same problem you noted with Opera, but across the browsers it works nicely and it's easy to integrate your functions and style the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another jQuery plugin, [Audero Context Menu](https://github.com/AurelioDeRosa/Audero-Context-Menu).