# A Javascript Context Menu?

Tags: javascript, menu, contextmenu

Im creating a web app that will need context menus when the user right clicks and have stumbled upon [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/wdContextMenu) one which i like very much. Im having a problem in that when i assign two div elements two different menus, the same menu appears for both. For example the code below creates two div elements, puts them onto the page and then assigns a seperate context menu for each of them.

```
this.leftDiv = document.createElement("div");
this.leftDiv.id = "Left_DIV";
document.body.appendChild(this.leftDiv);
$("#" + this.leftDiv.id).contextmenu(left_Options);
.........
this.rightDiv = document.createElement("div");
this.rightDiv.id = "Right_DIV";
document.body.appendChild(this.rightDiv);
$("#" + this.rightDiv.id).contextmenu(right_Options);
```

Now when the app is loaded in the browser, both of the divs have the left_Options menu system.

Would anyone be able to recommend a good javascript context menu that is easy to use?

Cheers.

Comment: What's in left_options and right_options ?

Comment: I found a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652456/context-menu-javascript?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Based on the site that you linked to, it looks as if one set of options is applied to *all* of the 'div' elements.  It presumes that you want to have similar options for all of your context menus.

In order to customize each individual menu, you add an 'onShow' option that can run a function enable/disable some items.  I'm not sure how flexible this is for completely different menus.

A quick search turned up this: http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/  It claims to support multiple menus on a single page, so perhaps that's what you're looking for.  I have not used it.

Comment: If you just want to use a div as a context menu, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app/4502207#4502207